# How can I refactor this Class in Java?

Tags: java

I am relatively new in learning java.

I have attempted to build a java class that search an array to check if the user input is listed in the array. If the value is in the array it this code prints out the the name of the website and the URL in the next array item.

I originally tried to use OOP and add the Scanner in its own class but I struggled to get the input from the scanner in the main method, when the Scanner was in a different class.

Ideally, I would have also wanted to add the for loop in a separate method to clean up the code, but I wasn't able to access the `websites.length` field when I added it in a separate class.

I would appreciate any help or ideas on how I could refactor this simple lines of code to improve performance or in line with Java best practices.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] websites = {"Google", "http://www.google.com", "Facebook", "http://www.facebook.com", "Ebay", "http://www.ebay.com", "Netflix", "http://www.netflix.com"};
    System.out.println("Enter Your Search Query");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
        if (userInput.equals(websites[i])) {
            System.out.println("We Found The Value");
            System.out.println(websites[i]);
            System.out.println(websites[i + 1]);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is no matching file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For such a small program I'd say it's fine as it is.

Comment: Other than "because it's my homework exercise and I have to use an array", is there a reason you're not using some `List<String>` and then simply testing using the `.contains` method?

Comment: You should consider using a `java.util.HashMap<String, String>` instead of a `String[]` for websites, and checking if `websites.containsKey(userInput)` without a loop.

Comment: not the best idea to print a not-found in the `else`  inside the loop - it will output not-found for each entry until the searched one is *found* || index can (should) be incremented by `2`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I didn't even think of using a HashMap but that make so much more sense. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user16320675 - I did actually find this issue when I did a compile and searched. It would come up with the 'There is no matching file' for each of the items that didn't match.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I refactor this Class in Java?

As Federico commented, for a program this small it is neither necessary or advisable to do this.  It is so small that splitting out parts of the code will not improve readability.

However, doing it *for the purpose of learning to program in Java* is not a bad thing.  So lets assume that *that* is your goal.

> I originally tried to use OOP and add the `Scanner` in it's own class but I struggled to get the input from the scanner in the main method, when the `Scanner` was in a different class.

Well, we would need to see what you did to understand your difficulty.

If the input requirements were complex, factoring them into a separate class (or even methods) might work.  But if you attempt it here, you end up adding many lines of code for no benefit.

Using OOP is not a *goal* in its own right.  It is a technique that you use to achieve other goals.  However, *learning to use* OOP is a goal.

> Ideally I would have also wanted to add the for loop in a separate method to clean up the code, but I wasn't able to access the `websites.length` field when I added it in a separate class.

You wouldn't put it in a separate class!  Put it in a separate method of your `Search` class.

The problem you most likely encountered is that `website` was out of scope because it was declared as a local variable within the `main` method.  To make `website` accessible in another method it either needs to be declared as a field, or you need to pass it as a parameter to the method.  Here is an *illustrative* example of the first way:

```
public class Search {

    private static String[] websites = {
        "Google", "http://www.google.com", 
        "Facebook", "http://www.facebook.com", 
        "Ebay", "http://www.ebay.com", 
        "Netflix", "http://www.netflix.com"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println("Enter Your Search Query");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = sc.nextLine();
        search(userInput);
    }
   
    private static void search(String userInput) {
        for (int i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) {
            if (userInput.equals(websites[i])) {
                System.out.println("We Found The Value");
                System.out.println(websites[i]);
                System.out.println(websites[i + 1]);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is no matching file");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is not a good example of a *useful* refactoring.  And it is not OO ... because we are using `static` methods and `static` fields.  But it illustrates how you can share things between different methods (and even classes) by using fields.

And ... once again ... OO is not a goal in its own right.  So the above is sufficient to meet your functional requirements.  But if you wanted to make the above more OO you *could*:

1. Make the `search` method an instance method by removing the `static`.
2. Call it like this:

   ```
   Search s = new Search();
   s.search(userInput);
   ```

(Making `websites` an instance field would probably be counter-productive.  If your requirements call for the searcher to check against a fixed set of websites, using a `static` for that is a natural way to do it.)

---

> I would appreciate any help or ideas on how I could refactor this simple lines of code to improve performance or in line with Java best practices.

First of all "best practice" is an *unhelpful* term in the context of programming / software engineering.  Please read [No Best Practices!](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164) to understand what I mean.

Second, there is nothing you can do to improve performance for this code in any *significant* way.  Starting up a Java JVM and loading your code will take 100s of milliseconds.  Waiting the the user's input will take seconds.  But the time to do the actual searching will be a couple of **microseconds**.  Your code's performance is irrelevant, in this example.

Now you could make the code simpler and more readable by doing either of the following:

- Change `websites` into 2 arrays, one containing the website names, and the other the corresponding URLs.  (Mixing the search keys and search values into one array leads to problems.)
- Change `websites` into `HashMap<String, String>` and you can then replace the loop with a `get` call.

But the flipside is that both of those will make initializing the `websites` more complicated.  (In a real application, would be loading that information from a configuration file, or searching a database ...)

Also, as noted in the comments, you could separate the functionality of searching from printing the results.  Read about the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle.